Does Smeared Joker work with other suit-specific jokers?
The description of the Smeared Joker says:

Hearts and Diamonds count as the same suit. Spades and Clubs count as the same suit.

Does this same-suit effect stack with other suit specific jokers? For example, the Greedy Joker says that "played cards with the Diamond suit give +3 multiplier when scored". If I had both Smeared Joker and Greedy Joker, would hearts give a +3 multiplier?


It stacks with absolutely everything in the game.
Smeared Joker makes all hearts cards count as both hearts and diamonds, for all purposes (and it also does the equivalent for the other three suits). It means that:

You can make flushes (and straight flushes, flush five, etc.) with any combination of hearts and diamonds (or clubs and spades).
Jokers that apply to one suit (like your example of Greedy Joker) will also apply to the other of the same color. It doesn't have to be a simple card like Greedy Joker, either - the wiki suggests combining it with Ancient Joker as well as several others.
Suit-debuff boss blinds will debuff both suits of a given color (because Smeared Joker makes them all match the debuff condition).
Any other effect that cares about the suit of a card will "see" every card as matching both applicable suits.

This is very similar to making every card a wild, except that they only match the other suit of the same color, instead of matching all four suits.

The suit-debuff bit is the only reason Smeared Joker isn't more broken than it already is. If you have Smeared, there are now four boss blinds that can each cripple 50% of your deck. It's still one of the best non-multiplicative Jokers in the game, especially if you have a voucher to reroll a bad blind.
